# Чем OpenVZ отличается от Xen?

Tags: xen, openvz, vps

Добрый вечер, выбираю VPS сервер для одного проекта, но не могу до конца понять чем технология виртуализации  OpenVZ отличается от Xen? И почему Xen везде стоит дороже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Чем отличается XEN от OpenVZ?](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/20209/)

[OpenVZ vs XEN](http://myubuntu.ru/component/kunena/11-virtualnye-servera-i-emulyatory/45-openvz-vs-xen)

Если по простому, Xen больше возможностей предоставляет.